# Remove part of the URL with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I've changed some settings in my website, and now I need to redirect from:

```
www.plugb.com/home/game/a
www.plugb.com/home/something/else
www.plugb.com/home/game/b
...
```

to

```
www.plugb.com/game/a
www.plugb.com/something/else
www.plugb.com/game/b
...
```

I don't know how to do this with .htaccess. BTW, I'm using CodeIgniter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use mod_rewrite and put the directives in your .htaccess.  Check [this](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html) out.